# Linking .a files in Mac OSx

Tags: macos, terminal, dylib, .a

I have added libxxx.a in /usr/lib but when I perform otool -L myproject.so, libxxx.a was not included in the list of libraries. I have also included libxxx.a in my build file so I was thinking that I have successfully added it.

How can I like .a file?

I didn't have a problem with .dylib files though.

Comment: Not your immediate problem, but for future reference never install stuff in /usr/lib - use /usr/local/lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`otool` won't show the static library as they are *included* within the executable binary (a `.dylib` in this case).  This is because static libraries are a collection of object (`.o`) files and it's pretty much the same as adding `file1.o ... fileN.o` to the linker command line and you can't see object files from `otool` either.

One way to check that your static library is part of the executable (other than it successfully linking) is to use the `nm` command which lists symbols.  Providing the executable binary is not *stripped*, you would do something like:

```
$ nm /path/to/libLibrary.dylib | grep aClassOrFunctionInStaticLibrary
```

and the symbol being searched should have the letter `t` next to it, to indicate that it's part of the executable *text* section.

Also as mentioned by @PaulR, `/usr/lib` is part of the operating system and you should not add files there; use `/usr/local/lib` instead as `/usr/local` is designed for site-specific additions to the system and files there will survive an operating system update.

Comment: Is .dylib static or dynamic?

Comment: @KcFnMi It’s dynamic. Dylib literally means “dynamic library”.